# Problem with IE7 link over jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, css

I'm testing a website using Jquery. 
I have a plugin that when you hover over it, it slides down revealing another banner thus sliding the banner below down. I've overlayed a link in  using z-index on the bottom banner, but whilst it works in other browsers I can't see it in IE7.

Any ideas why? Would moving the styles up help? Or moving the element above the banner in the html?

Thanks
Judi

Comment: Demo page or some code would help.

Comment: I'll post it tommorrow, I'm not at work at the moment and the site is currently being built offline. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like the ie z-index bug.
the fix is to loop through all related items and set its z-index like:

```
var zee_index = 1000;
$('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).css('zIndex',zee_index--);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit of a newbee at css. Can you explain how this works a little more?

Comment: <a href="#" id="quote-me-now-ad" onclick="openPopUp('<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetCallbackUrl"] %>')"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="QuoteMeNow" CssClass="quote-me-now" ImageUrl="/images/Quote-me-now-button.png" AlternateText="Quote me now" TabIndex="1" /></a>
<a class="TandCcontent" href="TermsAndConditions.aspx">† terms & conditions apply</a>

Comment: and css is =

div#secondary-content a.TandCcontent {z-index:2; position:relative; left:128px; bottom:22px; color:#0B57A4; font-size:1.1em;}

Answer (score 0):

IE gets funky with z-indexes if you don't put a 'position:' property in there.